# Android: WebView throws exception when trying fullscreen

Tags: java, android, webview

I tried to make a Webview and it works with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` But when I try to go fullscreen with either `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` or `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` or `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

It throws exception.

Here's the exception

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testing.view.webview/com.testing.view.webview.PinchoPancho}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

It tells me to use/add Theme.AppCompat but if I use it, it does not have the option to go fullscreen.

Everything else is default code so I will not post it. How could I go fullscreen using Theme.AppCompat?

Answer (score 0):

Try use this Theme

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm Sorry I'm new with Android Studio, where should I put this? In the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Use Immersive Full-Screen Mode

How to use this: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.htm